# How to update listview as user scroll down?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I want to make a listview that as user scroll to bottom of list view other items of list fill automatically from internet.I wrote code to that in the adapter of that expandable list view (within getGroupView() method)as like this,

```
public View getGroupView(final int arg0, final boolean arg1, View arg2, ViewGroup arg3) {
    //if(arg2==null){
        //arg2=act.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_exlistview_group, null);         
    }
    //((TextView)arg2.findViewById(R.id.nameText)).setText(item.getItemName());

    if(arg0>=getGroupCount()-1){//chech is near for end
        /*here i run a asynctask to download data and add items to SparseArray of this class.That sparsearray is the source to the adapter to view them in listview*/ 
    }

    //return arg2;
}
```

So is this correct way to do this or is there any good way to do that?

Comment: This should help http://benjii.me/2010/08/endless-scrolling-listview-in-android/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the fact that you're using `getGroupView` I assume you're using an `ExpandableListView`, not a regular `ListView`, which should probably be stated in your question.

Either way, the best way to do this would be to assign a [`OnScrollListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html) onto your list and then do your check there, rather than in `getGroupView`.

I'd recommend you put something along the lines of the following into your `onScroll` method:

```
if (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount > (totalItemCount - NUM_BEFORE_LOAD)) {
    loadMore()
}
```

where `NUM_BEFORE_LOAD` based on your example would be 1, but you could make it anything you want to make the list load quicker than when it hits the bottom.